# Deleting job log files on database

Tags: mysql, logs

Is it safe to delete job log files? I currently have 504,742 lines in my civicrm_job_log table, which comes to 223MB.

Comment: You might want to define 'safe' or rephrase this to say 'what will I lose by deleting this data'.

Comment: My host has shut down my site, and as far as I can tell it's mostly because regular queries to this table take over one second. It has 660k records. I'd like an answer to this question, as well as suggestions on how to do it properly.